# Spring SAML - Handling Assertions

Tags: spring-security, saml

Our application in part of another enterprise application(Parent). Our application is invoked as a child application from parent Web App. The user comes authenticated(SSO) on the parent app. There user clicks on a link and our application is popped up. Requirement is that we handle SAML assertion and use the attributes that come as part of the assertion. My question is do I need to have full hierarachy of spring saml beans, or if I just have "webSSOprofileConsumer" which corresponds to WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl, is enough

We have a requirement of handling SAML assertions where we need not worry about SSO/Authentication. Is it possible to do that in Spring SAML integration? If yes how.

Thanks,
M

Comment: add more details to your question

Comment: Let me try to re-phrase. Our application in part of another enterprise application(Parent). Our application is invoked as a child application from parent Web App. The user comes authenticated(SSO) on the parent app. There user clicks on a link and our application is popped up. Requirement is that we handle SAML assertion and use the attributes that come as part of the assertion. My question is do I need to have full hierarachy of spring saml beans, or if I just have "webSSOprofileConsumer" which corresponds to WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl, is enough.

Comment: Please add this to the question.I am not a domain expert in this topic I was review your question and added it to help you improve your question so that it gets more views and faster answers

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need complete Spring SAML beans for this. You can do with OpenSAML only - it is sufficient for parsing of Assertion and extracting attributes (which seems to be the only thing you seem to need).

The following code is an example of converting XML stream with SAML message into SAML object:

```
protected T unmarshallMessage(Reader messageStream) throws MessageDecodingException {
    log.debug("Parsing message stream into DOM document");

    try {
        Document messageDoc = getPool().parse(messageStream);
        Element messageElem = messageDoc.getDocumentElement();

        if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
            log.trace("Unmarshalled message into DOM:\n{}", XMLHelper.nodeToString(messageElem));
        }

        log.debug("Unmarshalling message DOM");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory().getUnmarshaller(messageElem);
        if (unmarshaller == null) {
            throw new MessageDecodingException(
                    "Unable to unmarshall message, no unmarshaller registered for message element "
                    + XMLHelper.getNodeQName(messageElem));
        }

        T message = (T) unmarshaller.unmarshall(messageElem);

        log.debug("Message successfully unmarshalled");
        return message;
    } catch (XMLParserException e) {
        log.error("Encountered error parsing message into its DOM representation", e);
        throw new MessageDecodingException("Encountered error parsing message into its DOM representation", e);
    } catch (UnmarshallingException e) {
        log.error("Encountered error unmarshalling message from its DOM representation", e);
        throw new MessageDecodingException("Encountered error unmarshalling message from its DOM representation", e);
    }
}
```

Call to getPool needs to return instance of `org.opensaml.xml.parse.ParserPool`, e.g. `BasicParserPool`.

The returned object will be e.g. of type `org.opensaml.saml2.core.Response` or `org.opensaml.saml2.core.Assertion` and you can find details of how to work with these objects in Spring SAML's codebase.

See e.g. `SAMLCredential#getAttributeAsStringArray` for details on handling of attributes.

You initialize OpenSAML by calling `org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap()` during initialization of your application.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. We already have spring in our application. 1. If we want to use spring-security-saml then what all we need to do.? 2. Please pardon my ignorance, where would the above code snippet that you mentioned would fit it?

Comment: You would need to include the Spring SAML dependency in your Maven (or include all the depedent jars manually) and include content from the securityContext.xml included in the Spring SAML sample to your current Spring Security application. The snippet I sent should be used in place where you need to parse the incoming SAML assertion.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. One more question. Before integration for this, I had one Spring Controller which handles all the application logic and we did not have any authentication. Now for handling this, does this controller need to handle the assertion logic(coming in body) as well or I need to write something extra(e.g. webSSOprofileConsumer). With webSSOprofileConsumer, I am not sure how the controller will get the details it needs from assertion. Thanks ~M

Comment: I have used the Spring sample securityContext, I am getting the following error `code` java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity ID criteria must be supplied
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.EntityIDCriteria.setEntityID(EntityIDCriteria.java:66)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.EntityIDCriteria.<init>(EntityIDCriteria.java:46)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager.getCredential(JKSKeyManager.java:189)

Comment: As you are using Spring Security for authentication/authorization in your application, you might need to handle processing of the token in a class which is able to correctly initialize Spring Security context - e.g. by extending AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter. You could most likely use Spring SAML with few extensions to do all you need to process/validate the Assertion and initialize Spring Security, but it might require deeper knowledge of the extension.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir, What should be my starting point towards deeper understanding of the extension. I have tried the sample application, and I guess my understanding is still not complete. I understand the our requirements are simple. 1. We have an existing app without any security. 2. We need to host it in a federated environment, where it needs to handle the assertion and get the required attributes from the assertion and use them in application logic. 3. I have a metadata file and public certificate from idp. Is it possible to list what all to use from the securityContext.xml?

Comment: Having a good understanding of Spring Security concepts and reading through Spring SAML sources should get you far. The approach to take could be customizing of SAMLProcessor to be able to obtain SAML message from whatever source you use (e.g. by defining new binding) and creating new implementation of WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl which accepts and verifies only Assertion without Response object.